# Installing external python package on HDInsight with Azure CLI : RdfeResourceHandlerException

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I want to install the pyobdc python package on a MS Azure HDInsight cluster, to use in a pyspark job.
Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation), I trying to get this done with a "script action".
The bash script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda install pyodbc
```

Among options, the script action can be submitted using the web interface (azure portal) or a CLI command line ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-linux)). In the web interface, the submit option is deactivated with the info "New script actions can be submitted after the current cluster operation finishes.". I have no idea what this cluster operation is.

I tried to used the CLI command line:

```
$ azure hdinsight script-action create my_cluster_name -g my_resource_group -n ipyodbc -u adl://my_data_lake_store.azuredatalakestore.net/clusters/scripts/script_actions/install_pyodbc.sh -t headnode;workernode
```

which fail with:

> info:    Executing command hdinsight script-action create /error:
>   Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.ClusterServices.RDFEProvider.ResourceTypes.Models.RdfeResourceHandlerException'
>   was thrown.
>   -error:   Error information has been recorded to /home/myself/.azure/azure.err error:   hdinsight script-action create
>   command failed

I tried to change the script location with a public uri (dropbox), I got the same error.
Any help or workaround would be much appreciated !
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the ambiguous error 'Microsoft.ClusterServices.RDFEProvider.ResourceTypes.Models.RdfeResourceHandlerException'.

In my case it was due to not including the path to conda in the command and simply using `conda` instead of `/usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda`.

Two things you might try to resolve your issue:

- remove sudo, you shouldn't need this for executing the command on the custer and potentially prompts for a password.
- add the -y switch to the command e.g. `/usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda install -y pyodbc` this prevents prompts

My assumption is that the `hdinsight script-action create` command doesn't like being held up and if it gets stuck it returns this uninformative and from what I could find (or couldn't) undocumented error.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up James. At the time I changed my workflow design to avoid deploying extra packages on HDInsight. I tried several approaches and commands variations. Unfortunately I have no longer my hands on the project, therefore I cannot check this.